# How to read nested struct Parquet files in Python?

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

I have a parquet file which contains list of structs and I cannot seem to read it with any of the available python parquet libraries. Some of them return an error noting that 'list of structs' is not yet supported and the others just make a pandas dataframe with None objects. If anyone has any experience with this it would help a lot. I have been banging my head with this for the last few days. Is there any other way to programmatically read the file somehow or convert that file to some other format and then read it ?

I want a python native support or c library can be called using Python that does not involving calling or starting other services like Spark.

Comment: What version of `pyarrow` are you using? You may have to upgrade to get support for list of struct

Comment: I am using 1.0.1 and that is the latest version @Arthur

Comment: This should now work with the latest pyarrow 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling pyarrow and install fastparquet. This worked for me. I was trying to convert it to CSV using pandas.